# Supremum and Infimum of the following sets

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to find the infimum and supremum of the following sets, however I can't check if my answers are correct. The sets are:

$$\begin{aligned}
&a)\,S=\{x\big|x=-(1/n)+[1+(-1)^n]n^2,n\geq1\}\\&\implies \sup S=\infty,\,\inf S=-1\\ \\
&b)\, S = \{x\in\mathbb{Q}\big|x^2<2\}\\&\implies \sup S=\sqrt2,\,\inf S=-\sqrt2\\ \\
&c)\,S=\{x\big| |2x+1|<5\}\\&\implies \sup S=2,\,\inf S=-3\\ \\
&e)\,S=\{x\big|(x^2+1)^{-1}>1/2\}\\&\implies \sup S=1,\,\inf S=-1
\end{aligned}$$
Would these results be correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.